# Borrar registros utilizando una tabla generada por un query

Tags: php, sqlsrv

he estado tratando de borrar los registros de una tabla en SQL server mediante un boton de borrar, utilizando una tabla producto de un query. A como lo tengo ahora, al dar click al boton procede a actualizarse la página, sin embargo no borra la fila con el ID que indico en el código.

El siguiente es mi código:

```php
    <?php
include("includes/connect.php");

if(isset($_POST['procesar'])){
  $fechaDesde = $_POST['fechaDesde'];
  $fecha1 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($fechaDesde));
  $fechaHasta = $_POST['fechaHasta'];
  $fecha2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($fechaHasta));
  $params = [
    [$fecha1,    SQLSRV_PARAM_IN],
    [$fecha2,    SQLSRV_PARAM_IN],
  ];
  $query ="{call mostrar_movimientos2(?,?)}";
  $resultado = sqlsrv_query($con, $query, $params);
if ($resultado != false){
  while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($resultado, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo "<tr><th scope='row'>{$row['id']}</th>";
    if ($row['concepto'] != 'Cheques'){
      echo "<th scope='row'><p class='text-success'>$";
      echo "{$row['importe']}</p></th>";
    } else{
      echo "<th scope='row'><p class='text-danger'>-$";
      echo "{$row['importe']}</p></th>";
    }
    
    echo "<th scope='row'>{$row['concepto']}</th>";
    echo "<th scope='row'>{$row['fecha_movimiento']}</th>";
    echo "<th scope='row'><button type='submit' name='borrar' class='btn btn-danger'>X</button></th></tr>";
  }
} else{
  echo('Algo salió mal: ');
    print_r(sqlsrv_errors());
    die();
}
  if(isset($_POST['borrar'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $intid = (int)$id;
    $queryd ="DELETE from movimientos where id = '$id'";
    $resultadod = sqlsrv_query($con, $queryd);
    }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Depura, por ejemplo haz `var_dump($id);` después de declarar `$id`. Y un apunte: tienes `$intid` pero luego usas `$id` en la consulta.

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP Saqué el codigo de donde estaba y lo puse al final de mi página para ver el dump, me sale lo siguiente:
Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\pos\modulos\movimientos.php on line 135

Comment: Eso significa que `$_GET['id']` no está definido, osea, no estás recibiendo id por GET. Quizá lo estés enviando por POST, usa `$id = $_POST['id'];` a ver.

Comment: Tenías toda la razon, estaba usando el método POST y por lo tanto el GET no capturaba nada. Muchas gracias!